# Error al instalar paquete NPM jspdf

Tags: git, pdf, npm

Estoy tratando de generar un pdf a un lisatdo de una tabla.Pero al tratar de instalar npm install jspdf me da error.Y este error solo me da al instalar este modulo.

```
npm install jspdf
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
```

Comment: Quizás pregunto algo obvio, pero tienes GIT instalado no?

Comment: No no tengo GIT instalada.Estoy desarrollando en Angular/cli": "^8.1.2" y no se si este npm package este disponible para la version porque los demas package si se me instalan.Saludos

Comment: Pero el paquete jspdf requiere de git para su instalación. Instala git y luego intentas instalar de nuevo el paquete. Con eso debería ser suficiente.